# Setting all values to 0 except those returned by argpartition in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to create a sparse matrix for based on a n*n distance matrix keeping the k smallest values in the distance matrix for each row. I have got the correct indices back by using `np.argpartition`, but when I try and create a mask from this all it does is select the diagonal as True and everything else as false.

```
nn_indices = np.argpartition(data, k - 1)[:, :k]
mask = np.isin(data, nn_indices)
```

Any idea how I use the output from `argpartition` to create a boolean mask for those indices?

e.g. - for n = 4, k = 2

```
[[4, 6, 1, 3]
 [1, 5, 6, 7]
 [4, 7, 2, 3]
 [7, 1, 8, 2]]
```

Argpartition output:

```
[[2, 3]
 [0, 1]
 [2, 3]
 [1, 3]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 3]
 [1, 5, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 2, 3]
 [0, 1, 0, 2]]
```

I have had a look at `scipy.csr_matrix` but can't get my head around how to order the column and row data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the `scipy.sparse` will help here.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny The `argsort` solution gives incorrect results on the last row.

Comment: @MechanicPig - Must be `np.where(data.argsort().argsort() < k, data, 0)`, that's not a nice solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate an array of all zeros and then simply fill it:

```
>>> mask = np.zeros(data.shape, bool)
>>> mask[np.arange(len(data))[:, None], nn_indices] = True
>>> mask
array([[False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True]])
>>> np.where(mask, data, 0)
array([[0, 0, 1, 3],
       [1, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: I benchmarked possible optimizations in a [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vz9rSHtwdtI6v_0Sq6k_UqRITvcwJ8qh?usp=sharing). No clear winner with different sparsity and array sizes.